# Does anyone have experience using stackmob as backend for a phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, stackmob

What do you recommend to use as backend for a phonegap app tha just needs to allow login, save  some user data and send notifications?

Comment: I've written [a blog post about exactly that](http://javanto.com/blog/2012/06/13/stackmob-with-phonegap/). Using [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth), it's totally possible to log in to StackMob and make requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the Platform Evangelist with StackMob.

You can run things on PhoneGap. We're building out official support for it soon with respect to security, but in preparation, the JS SDK has already been updated to do so, taking advantage of the fact that PhoneGap's browser allows cross domain ajax calls. Just put this in your StackMob.init:

StackMob.init({ 
... 
fullURL: true, 
... 
});

And it should work! We haven't documented it officially yet so as to bundle it with OAuth 2.0 support in the very very near future.

The above step assumes you've already linked your GitHub account and hence have enabled our proxying server. When we officially support PhoneGap, we're going to update a getting started flow that doesn't require GitHub.

Comment: Any way you can be more specific about the timeframe for "official support"?